# Post man works but reactjs fetch not working

Tags: reactjs

I use reactjs to post a comment via API. As I use Postman it works well but on reactjs, it does not work. Can you check my code ?

```
export function createComment(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3RcL3N5bXBsZSIsImlhdCI6MTU0MzI5MTYyMSwibmJmIjoxNTQzMjkxNjIxLCJleHAiOjE1NDM4OTY0MjEsImRhdGEiOnsidXNlciI6eyJpZCI6IjIifX19.PAtLgv_AZ4sdLhuqirIg1HMidkFxYwNe7t1yr4MMspM";
  return fetch('http://localhost/website/wp-json/wp/v2/comments', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      "headers": {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token, 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  }).then(res => {
      return res;
  }).catch(err => err);
}
```

Issue on console is : `401 (Unauthorized)`, 
console.log(data) still work:

```
{author_name: "ha", author_email: "blabla@gmail.com", author_url: "https://google.com", content: "31231231232131", post: 65, …}
```

Below is code of postMan:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost/website/wp-json/wp/v2/comments',
  qs: 
   { author_name: 'babahaha',
     author_email: 'ha90@gmail.com',
     author_url: 'https://google.com',
     content: 'hello',
     parent: '0',
     post: '65' },
  headers: 
   { 'Postman-Token': '2b4db31d-b1f5-4c74-b78b-a80cfe9d6d80',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     Authorization: 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3RcL3N5bXBsZSIsImlhdCI6MTU0MzI5MTYyMSwibmJmIjoxNTQzMjkxNjIxLCJleHAiOjE1NDM4OTY0MjEsImRhdGEiOnsidXNlciI6eyJpZCI6IjIifX19.PAtLgv_AZ4sdLhuqirIg1HMidkFxYwNe7t1yr4MMspM' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: You might want to consider using AXIOS instead

Comment: @ShawnAndrews Axios is ok. Can you suggest me?

Comment: Check the Network tab on your browser to see if `Authorization` header is included in request header. It could be omitted hence you receive `401`.

Comment: @Khang Thank you. I see problem. Because I already signed in so I cannot use test token

Comment: Also pay attention to `cookies` if you use it for identifying users because `fetch` does not send `cookies` by default.